# Using Scrapy with multiple tables only having style info

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, html-table

I got into trouble when I try to extract the HTML text of a certain table from several tables on a website. There is no id or class info under the source code. Each table starts with this:

```
<table style='width:800px;border:solid  #48f 1px;text-align:left;line-height:14px;font-size:11px;'>...

<table style='width:900px;border:solid  #48f 1px;text-align:left;line-height:18px;font-size:11px;'>...

<table style='width:650px;line-height:22px;'>...
```

How can I select the third table using Scrapy? Or another method?

Answer (score 0):

using xpath you can select them by position, for the third table do:

```
//table[3]
```

note that xpath index starts from 1

see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for more xpath syntax